# Why SelectList returning Null value in model when submitting post?

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller, razor, selectlist

I'm trying to submit a form using Html helper like this:

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Certificate", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", id = "complianceCertificate" }))
```

Onload of page, I'm binding the dropdown using HTML helper like this

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model._DetailsOfOwner.Id, Model._DetailsOfOwner.Practices, "Select licensee name...", new { @class = "form-control tx-13 pd-2 has-check-valid", @name = "LicenseeId" })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model._DetailsOfOwner.Practices, "", new { @class = "text-danger has-error-valid" })
```

It loaded correctly
[image]

The problem is when submitting the form. It passes `null` value in model of `SelectList`.
[image]

Here is my class where select list located

```
public class _DetailsOfOwnerViewModel : BaseAddress
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public SelectList Practices { get; set; }
    public string LicenseeName { get; set; }
    public string RMLNo { get; set; }
    public string ContactPerson { get; set; }
    public string Telephone { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

Thank  you.

Comment: your form is in a razor page? and your project is Asp.net framework or core?

Comment: @nima asp.net mvc

Answer (score 1):

You cant return complete SelectList you need to select a single value from dropdown that will be returned to server. You should change your model.

Switch this

```
public SelectList Practices { get; set; }
```

to this

```
public string Practices { get; set; }
```

Comment: Hi @sandeep, I'll just use the `model._DetailsOfOwner.Id ` to get the selected record on my list.

Comment: No @Raymond you cant do this in model. U have to assign all items using viewbag etc.

Comment: Hi @sandeep, I integrated the SelectList in my class so I don't have much coding in my controller. It makes the binding of data to selectlist easier, same with the initialization of form. Since my select list is bound to the `model._DetailsOfOwner.Id` I can get the selected Id in my model.

Answer (score 0):

A dropdown list when an item has been chosen maps to a single value rather than a list of values so the model isn't being bound properly on submission. Try changing the type of Practicies to an int or a string.

Comment: Hi @justAnotherDev, Yep, dropdown list is not bounded to the model. I'll just use the model._DetailsOfOwner.Id to get the selected value.

Answer (score 0):

Here, You are binding a dropdown from the model object and may b that's why you take SelectList for practices property. But when you receive form data using the post method at that time you have only a single value selected in the dropdown so you need int or string for that.
So there is two way to fix it:

Bind dropdown by using ViewBag, in which you will assign your list and replace

> public SelectList Practices {get;set;}

to

> public string Practices {get;set;}

and bind dropdown by using model._DetailsOfOwner.Practices property instead of model._DetailsOfOwner.Id.

OR another way is

You are binding the model._DetailsOfOwner.Id in the dropdown so simply you can get selected value from that property.